# Trouble passing arguments through an initialiser function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I am having trouble passing arguments through a new object when using an initialiser function. Consider my following examples that I want to be able to create an object that returns an array. Object Ex1 does this fine:

```
Ex1 = function() {

    myVar = [];
    myVar = Array.apply( myVar, arguments );
    return myVar;

};

ex1 = new Ex1( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );
console.log( ex1);
/* ["red", "green", "blue"] */
```

However, I want to us an initialiser to keep my code clean. Object Ex2 shows my unexpected result:

```
Ex2 = function() {

    init = function() {
        myVar = [];
        myVar = Array.apply( myVar, arguments );
        return myVar;
    };

    return init( arguments );

};

ex2 = new Ex2( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );
console.log( ex2 );
/* [[object Arguments] {
   0: "red",
   1: "green",
   2: "blue"
   }] */
```

As you can see from the log the result is not a clean array.

How do I return an array when creating a new object when using an initialiser function and passing arguments to it?

Comment: You need to learn to use local variables…

Comment: A very helpful comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not hard to understand. In a function, `arguments` is an array-like object which contains all the arguments passed in. In your second example, you passed an array as argument to init function, so `arguments` in init function is a 2D array.

```
Ex2 = function() {   
    init = function() {
        myVar = [];
        myVar = Array.apply( myVar, arguments );//arguments: [["red", "green", "blue"]]
        return myVar;
    };

    return init( arguments );//arguments: ["red", "green", "blue"]  
};
```

You could use a parameter for example:

```
Ex2 = function() {
    var init = function(argu) {
        return Array.apply( 0, argu );//argu: ["red", "green", "blue"]
    };
    return init( arguments );
};
ex2 = new Ex2( 'red', 'green', 'blue' );
console.log( ex2 );//["red", "green", "blue"]
```

Another thing is declaring a variable without `var` will put it in global scope.

Comment: Ah I see now. By passing the arguments object as an argument it is getting wrapped within another arguments object. Thanks... Your post and a good nights sleep has helped me understand. :)